# Open PGM image in Java

Tags: java, pgm

I need to read a PGM image and get its points in Java.
Anyone knows a good library to do that?

I have to display an image with PGM format and then get the values from that image to draw a path with A*.

Cumps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922252/reading-a-pgm-file-in-java

Comment: thanks, it works fine ;) it allows me to get the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PGM is a simple format. You can read it manually.

It's **specification** is given [here](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html).

Also, [this](http://www.cs.olemiss.edu/~jxue/teaching/csci112_S11/notes/hw1/PgmImage.java) provides code to **read it and display** on a `Component`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. It makes my work easier :D

Comment: Glad to know it helped.